# How to plot in multiple subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I am a little confused about how this code works:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
plt.show()
```

How does the fig, axes work in this case? What does it do?

Also why wouldn't this work to do the same thing:

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

Answer (score 334, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. The `subplots` method creates the figure along with the subplots that are then stored in the `ax` array. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        col.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, something like this will also work, it's not so "clean" though since you are creating a figure with subplots and then add on top of them:

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you do this exact same thing when you want to plot an `object`, as opposed to something where you can separate `x` and `y` cleanly like in your example?

Answer (score 102):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax[0, 0].plot(range(10), 'r') #row=0, col=0
ax[1, 0].plot(range(10), 'b') #row=1, col=0
ax[0, 1].plot(range(10), 'g') #row=0, col=1
ax[1, 1].plot(range(10), 'k') #row=1, col=1
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I get what `ax` is, but not what is `fig`. What are they?

Comment: ax is actually a numpy array. fig is `matplotlib.figure.Figure` class through which you can do a lot of manipulation to the plotted figure. for example, you can add colorbar to specific subplot, you can change the background color behind all subplots. you can modify the layout of these subplots or add a new small ax to them. preferably you might want a single main title for all subplots which can be obtained through `fig.suptitle(title)` method. finally once you are happy with the plot, you can save it using `fig.savefig` method. @Leevo

Answer (score 36):

- You can also unpack the axes in the subplots call
- And set whether you want to share the x and y axes between the subplots

Like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4 = axes.flatten()

ax1.plot(range(10), 'r')
ax2.plot(range(10), 'b')
ax3.plot(range(10), 'g')
ax4.plot(range(10), 'k')
plt.show()
```

[image: 2 x 2 plot]

Answer (score 19):

You might be interested in the fact that as of matplotlib version 2.1 the second code from the question works fine as well.

From the [change log](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#figure-class-now-has-subplots-method):

> Figure class now has subplots method
>   The Figure class now has a subplots() method which behaves the same as pyplot.subplots() but on an existing figure.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

Read the documentation: [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)

`pyplot.subplots()` returns a tuple `fig, ax` which is unpacked in two variables using the notation

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

The code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

does not work because `subplots()` is a function in `pyplot` not a member of the object `Figure`.

Answer (score 9):

### Subplots with `pandas`

- This answer is for subplots with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which uses [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) as the default plotting backend.
- Here are four options to create subplots starting with a `pandas.DataFrame`

  - Implementation 1. and 2. are for the data in a wide format, creating subplots for each column.
  - Implementation 3. and 4. are for data in a long format, creating subplots for each unique value in a column.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

#### Imports and Data

```py
import seaborn as sns  # data only
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# wide dataframe
df = sns.load_dataset('planets').iloc[:, 2:5]

   orbital_period   mass  distance
0         269.300   7.10     77.40
1         874.774   2.21     56.95
2         763.000   2.60     19.84
3         326.030  19.40    110.62
4         516.220  10.50    119.47

# long dataframe
dfm = sns.load_dataset('planets').iloc[:, 2:5].melt()

         variable    value
0  orbital_period  269.300
1  orbital_period  874.774
2  orbital_period  763.000
3  orbital_period  326.030
4  orbital_period  516.220
```

#### 1. `subplots=True` and `layout`, for each column

- Use the parameters `subplots=True` and `layout=(rows, cols)` in [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- This example uses `kind='density'`, but there are different options for `kind`, and this applies to them all. Without specifying `kind`, a line plot is the default.
- `ax` is array of `AxesSubplot` returned by `pandas.DataFrame.plot`
- See [How to get a `Figure` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14936646/7758804), if needed.

  - [How to save pandas subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19555525/7758804)

```py
axes = df.plot(kind='density', subplots=True, layout=(2, 2), sharex=False, figsize=(10, 6))

# extract the figure object; only used for tight_layout in this example
fig = axes[0][0].get_figure() 

# set the individual titles
for ax, title in zip(axes.ravel(), df.columns):
    ax.set_title(title)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### 2. `plt.subplots`, for each column

- Create an array of [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) with [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and then pass `axes[i, j]` or `axes[n]` to the `ax` parameter.

  - This option uses [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), but can use other `axes` level plot calls as a substitute (e.g. `sns.kdeplot`, `plt.plot`, etc.)
  - It's easiest to collapse the subplot array of `Axes` into one dimension with [`.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html). See [`.ravel` vs `.flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/7758804).
  - Any variables applying to each `axes`, that need to be iterate through, are combined with [`.zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) (e.g. `cols`, `axes`, `colors`, `palette`, etc.). Each object must be the same length.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))  # define the figure and subplots
axes = axes.ravel()  # array to 1D
cols = df.columns  # create a list of dataframe columns to use
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green']  # list of colors for each subplot, otherwise all subplots will be one color

for col, color, ax in zip(cols, colors, axes):
    df[col].plot(kind='density', ax=ax, color=color, label=col, title=col)
    ax.legend()
    
fig.delaxes(axes[3])  # delete the empty subplot
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Result for 1. and 2.

[image]

#### 3. `plt.subplots`, for each group in `.groupby`

- This is similar to 2., except it zips `color` and `axes` to a [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))  # define the figure and subplots
axes = axes.ravel()  # array to 1D
dfg = dfm.groupby('variable')  # get data for each unique value in the first column
colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green']  # list of colors for each subplot, otherwise all subplots will be one color

for (group, data), color, ax in zip(dfg, colors, axes):
    data.plot(kind='density', ax=ax, color=color, title=group, legend=False)

fig.delaxes(axes[3])  # delete the empty subplot
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### 4. [`seaborn` figure-level plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

- Use a `seaborn` figure-level plot, and use the `col` or `row` parameter. `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`. See [seaborn: API reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html).

```py
p = sns.displot(data=dfm, kind='kde', col='variable', col_wrap=2, x='value', hue='variable',
                facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False}, height=3.5, aspect=1.75)
sns.move_legend(p, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(.55, .45))
```

Answer (score 6):

Iterating through all subplots sequentially:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

Accessing a specific index:

```py
for row in range(nrows):
    for col in range(ncols):
        axes[row,col].plot(x[row], y[col])
```

Answer (score 5):

### Convert the `axes` array to 1D

- Generating subplots with [`plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), where **both** nrows and ncols is greater than 1, returns a nested array of `<AxesSubplot:>` objects.

  - It’s not necessary to flatten `axes` in cases where either `nrows=1` or `ncols=1`, because `axes` will already be 1 dimensional, which is a result of the default parameter `squeeze=True`
- The easiest way to access the objects, is to convert the array to 1 dimension with [`.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), [`.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), or [`.flat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html).

  - [`.ravel` vs. `.flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/7758804)

    - `flatten` always returns a copy.
    - `ravel` returns a view of the original array whenever possible.
- Once the array of `axes` is converted to 1-d, there are a number of ways to plot.
- This answer is relevant to seaborn axes-level plots, which have the `ax=` parameter (e.g. `sns.barplot(…, ax=ax[0])`.

  - `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`. See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) and [seaborn is not plotting within defined subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63895570/7758804)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  # sample data only

# example of data
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
y_data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in range(1, 5)])
x_data = [rads, rads, rads, rads]

# Generate figure and its subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

# axes before
array([[<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
       [<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>]], dtype=object)

# convert the array to 1 dimension
axes = axes.ravel()

# axes after
array([<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>],
      dtype=object)
```

1. Iterate through the flattened array

   - If there are more subplots than data, this will result in `IndexError: list index out of range`

     - Try option 3. instead, or select a subset of the axes (e.g. `axes[:-2]`)

```py
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(x_data[i], y_data[i])
```

2. Access each axes by index

```py
axes[0].plot(x_data[0], y_data[0])
axes[1].plot(x_data[1], y_data[1])
axes[2].plot(x_data[2], y_data[2])
axes[3].plot(x_data[3], y_data[3])
```

3. Index the data and axes

```py
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    axes[i].plot(x_data[i], y_data[i])
```

4. `zip` the axes and data together and then iterate through the list of tuples.

```py
for ax, x, y in zip(axes, x_data, y_data):
    ax.plot(x, y)
```

### Ouput

[image]

---

- An option is to assign each axes to a variable, `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)`. However, as written, this only works in cases with either `nrows=1` or `ncols=1`. This is based on the shape of the array returned by `plt.subplots`, and quickly becomes cumbersome.

  - `fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)` for a 2 x 2 array.
  - This is most useful for two subplots (e.g.: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)` or `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)`). For more subplots, it's more efficient to flatten and iterate through the array of axes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, _ = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
  ax.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100) + np.pi/2*i))
```

[image: code result: plots]

Or alternatively, using the second variable that `plt.subplot` returns:

```
fig, ax_mat = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for i, ax in enumerate(ax_mat.flatten()):
    ...
```

`ax_mat` is a matrix of the axes. It's shape is nrows x ncols.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `add_subplot` in `matplotlib`. In my opinion, it's easier than accessing subplots in the `axes` array:

```
funcs = [np.cos, np.sin, np.tan, np.arctan, np.exp, np.log]
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# iterate over the function list and add a subplot for each function
for idx, func in enumerate(funcs, start=1):  
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, idx) # plot with 2 rows and 3 columns
    ax.plot(x, func(x))
    ax.set_title(func.__name__)

# add spacing between subplots
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=False)
for sp in fig.axes:
    sp.plot(range(10))
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Go with the following if you really want to use a loop:

```
def plot(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100, 100))
    for idx, k in enumerate(data.keys(), 1):
        x, y = data[k].keys(), data[k].values
        plt.subplot(63, 10, idx)
        plt.bar(x, y)  
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Another concise solution is:

```js
// set up structure of plots
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20,10))

// for plot 1
ax1.set_title('Title A')
ax1.plot(x, y)

// for plot 2
ax2.set_title('Title B')
ax2.plot(x, y)

// for plot 3
ax3.set_title('Title C')
ax3.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: As written, this option only works in cases with either `nrows=1` or `ncols=1`. This quickly becomes inefficient for anything other than `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)` or `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)`, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804)