# How do I automatically plot columns of a dataframe in separate subplots? w/python-matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I draw multiple plots for each group of data from the same dataframe?

My data is:

```
Fecha          IP        count
---------- --------------- -----
2017/06/03 115.159.241.160     1
2017/06/03 116.31.116.21    1268
2017/06/03 116.31.116.27     432
2017/06/03 122.4.172.199       1
2017/06/03 153.187.102.60      1
2017/06/03 171.8.75.134        1
2017/06/03 188.16.161.176      1
2017/06/03 190.179.128.206     1
2017/06/03 190.50.203.101      1
2017/06/03 193.201.224.215    31
2017/06/03 193.70.95.180       1
2017/06/03 201.179.182.64      1
2017/06/03 221.122.101.203     1
2017/06/03 221.229.60.6        1
2017/06/03 58.218.198.160    832
2017/06/03 58.218.198.161   1981
2017/06/03 60.190.98.50        1
2017/06/03 72.2.170.24         1
2017/06/03 77.53.124.27        1
2017/06/03 91.197.232.108     17
2017/06/03 91.197.232.11      31
2017/06/03 95.5.136.211        1
2017/06/04 114.113.234.66      1
2017/06/04 116.31.116.21     148
2017/06/04 116.31.116.27     975
2017/06/04 118.102.213.245     1
2017/06/04 122.232.8.113       1
2017/06/04 124.173.118.39      1
2017/06/04 174.90.226.4        1
2017/06/04 182.243.91.32       1
2017/06/04 185.70.28.137       3
2017/06/04 192.81.214.183      3
2017/06/04 193.70.86.63       42
2017/06/04 195.66.220.121      1
2017/06/04 202.4.110.75        3
2017/06/04 203.185.22.28       3
2017/06/04 218.104.207.53      1
2017/06/04 27.223.195.200      1
2017/06/04 31.44.116.54        1
2017/06/04 49.248.112.46       1
2017/06/04 58.218.198.160   2611
2017/06/04 58.218.198.161    262
2017/06/04 58.248.66.53        1
2017/06/04 58.68.23.70         1
2017/06/04 61.163.231.213      1
2017/06/04 83.219.73.102       2
2017/06/04 88.201.33.141       1
2017/06/04 89.166.222.253      1
2017/06/04 93.97.193.152       1
```

I am plotting all together data in a one graph:

[image: fig 1]

with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from  matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter

df = pd.read_csv("DaysCountIP.csv", delimiter=',', parse_dates = ['Fecha'])
grupos = df.groupby(['IP'])

print df

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,6.5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.06, right=None, top=.95, bottom=None)

color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(grupos))))

for nombre, grupo in grupos:
    ax.plot_date(grupo['Fecha'].values, 
                 grupo['count'].values, 
                 color=next(color), marker='o', ls='solid', label=nombre)
    for x, y in zip(grupo['Fecha'],grupo['count']):
        annotation_string = (nombre) 
        annotation_string += "\n"
        annotation_string += "%.0f" % (y)
        ax.annotate(annotation_string, xy=(x,y),
        xytext=(0,15),
        textcoords='offset points', size=6.5, ha='center', va='center',
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.3', fc='white', alpha=None),
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))

locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.margins(0.05)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(ncol=3, fontsize='x-small',loc='center left', title='IPs',  bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.4))

plt.show()
```

I want to draw each group (nombre), each on different graph into the same canvas/figure.

Is this possible?

> ## º----------------------------- *UPDATE 13/06/2017* -----------------------------º

I am looking to graph a different graph into a loop for each group element in one figure (plot area), something like this: (the image has been generated in splunk):

[image: figure 2]

> ## º----------------------------- *UPDATE 14/06/2017* -----------------------------º

I tried this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=18, ncols=2)

for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        for nombre, grupo in grupos:
            col.plot_date(grupo['Fecha'].values,
                         grupo['count'].values)

locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
col.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
col.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

But I can't isolate each group by graph, the code graph al data in every plot graph.

[image: Error]

Also rarely the date format is only taken for the second column of graphs.

My dataset is:

```
[In] type(df)
[Out] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Is your question essentially "How do I create subplots in matplotlib?"? Because in that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib

Comment: Really not, I am looking fir that, see UPDATE 13/06/2017

Comment: What you are showing there are subplots :|

Comment: ok, let me review better your suggestion. Thanks @AndrasDeak

Comment: @AndrasDeak I tried with... the results up above

Comment: I don't think so, i can't do it manually, the length of the dataframe is always different, i will get a variable for nrow. My problem is with the loop for the plot, not in the layout.

Comment: Well my latter suggestion avoids a loop. If you're doing the loop like in your updated question, you need to explicitly plot a given part of your dataframe at a time. So instead of plotting every `grupo` for every axes, you only plot _one_ `grupo` for every axes. Do you understand what I mean?