# Place the plots on the page in two columns

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

I built a graph according to the dictionary data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

TNRACG_T_OLD= {'need1': 27, 'need2': 36}
plt.bar(range(len(TNRACG_T_OLD)), TNRACG_T_OLD.values(), align='center', color='b', label="TNRACG_T_OLD")
plt.xticks(range(len(TNRACG_T_OLD)), TNRACG_T_OLD.keys())
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 1), ncol=1)
plt.ylabel(u'Costs of meeting needs,')
plt.xlabel(u'Name of needs')

plt.show()

TNRCG_T_OLD= {'need1': 120, 'need2': 72}
plt.bar(range(len(TNRCG_T_OLD)), TNRCG_T_OLD.values(), align='center', color='b', label="TNRCG_T_OLD")
plt.xticks(range(len(TNRCG_T_OLD)), TNRCG_T_OLD.keys())
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 1), ncol=1)
plt.ylabel(u'Costs of meeting needs,')
plt.xlabel(u'Name of needs')

plt.show()
```

[image]
The default graphics are placed to the right one column.

What to fix in the code of the program, so that the graphs are placed in two columns. As shown below.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the answer to my question? I unfortunately did not find such a question.

Comment: You need to create two subplots within a figure as shown in the duplicate. Alternatively, Google "matplotlib subplots"

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib) perhaps gives another explanation.

Comment: If a similar question was asked earlier. Should I delete this question?

Comment: You can either leave it as a duplicate, or delete it, it's up to you.