# Plot multiple histograms as a grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am trying to plot multiple histograms on the same window using a list of tuples. I have managed to get it to sketch only 1 tuple at a time and I just can't seem to get it to work with all of them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2),(2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2),(3,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,1)] #my list of tuples

q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10 = zip(*a) #split into [(1,0,1,2,3) ,(2,2,2,0,1),..etc] where q1=(1,0,1,2,3)

labels, counts = np.unique(q1,return_counts=True) #labels = 0,1,2,3 and counts the occurence of 0,1,2,3

ticks = range(len(counts))
plt.bar(ticks,counts, align='center')
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
plt.show()
```

As you can see from the above code, I can plot one tuple at a time say q1,q2 etc but how do I generalise it so that it plots all of them.

I've tried to mimic this [python plot multiple histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467077/python-plot-multiple-histograms), which is exactly what I want however I had no luck.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a grid of axes with [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) taking into account the amount of tuples in the list, and how many you want per row. Then iterate over the returned axes, and plot the histograms in the corresponding axis. You could use [Axes.hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html), but I've always preferred to use [`ax.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), from the result of `np.unique`, which also can return the counts of unique values:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l = list(zip(*a))
n_cols = 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=int(np.ceil(len(l)/n_cols)), 
                         ncols=n_cols, 
                         figsize=(15,15))

for i, (t, ax) in enumerate(zip(l, axes.flatten())):
    labels, counts = np.unique(t, return_counts=True)
    ax.bar(labels, counts, align='center', color='blue', alpha=.3)
    ax.title.set_text(f'Tuple {i}')

plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can customise the above to whatever amount of rows/cols you prefer, for `3` rows for instance:

```
l = list(zip(*a))
n_cols = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=int(np.ceil(len(l)/n_cols)), 
                         ncols=n_cols, 
                         figsize=(15,15))

for i, (t, ax) in enumerate(zip(l, axes.flatten())):
    labels, counts = np.unique(t, return_counts=True)
    ax.bar(labels, counts, align='center', color='blue', alpha=.3)
    ax.title.set_text(f'Tuple {i}')

plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I should be able to see 10 histograms.I see in the following line ```for i, (t, ax) in enumerate(zip(a, axes.flatten())): ``` the tuples are not the tuples I need, I need (1,0,1,2,3), (2,2,2,0,1) etc not (1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2) (0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
(2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
(3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1)

Comment: Basically I need the first/second/third... element of every tuple to be a tuple and then plot that in its own histogram.

Comment: Gotcha, check now @alan

Comment: Thanks @yatu. Stay safe :)

Comment: Just a quick quest @yatu, it's not possible to change the labels to some string like 0->A 1-->B etc since its a tuple? Sorry for all the questions, I am not good with matplot module.

Comment: Just letters from the alphabet like that? @alan

Comment: All good, I figured it out.I went back to see where I got my tuples from and changed the values to A,B etc. So now my tuples are in strings rather than integers. Thanks for your help!