# Adding subplots to figure using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics, heatmap

I am trying to add 8 heatmaps (subplots) to a figure but I can't seem to manage it. Could you please help me?

```
# in order to modify the size
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
# adding multiple Axes objects  
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 4)  # a figure with a 2x4 grid of Axes

letter = "ABCDEFGH"

for character in letter:
    x = np.random.randn(4096)
    y = np.random.randn(4096)
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(64,64))
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

    # Plot heatmap
    plt.clf()
    plt.title('Pythonspot.com heatmap example')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you were creating two separate figures by calling
`plt.figure()` and then `plt.subplots()` (that last function creates both a figure and an array of axes)

Then you need to iterate over your axes, and plot on each one of these axes, instead of clearing the figure at each loop (which is what you were doing using `plt.clf()`)

You can use the `plt.XXXX()` functions, but those only work on the "current" axes, so you have to change the current axes at each iteration. Otherwise, you would be better off using the `Axes.set_XXXX()` functions, like in the other answer by @yatu. See [here for more information](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html#a-note-on-the-object-oriented-api-vs-pyplot).
    fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(12,8))  # a figure with a 2x4 grid of Axes

```
letters = "ABCDEFGH"
for character,ax in zip(letters, ax_lst.flat):
    x = np.random.randn(4096)
    y = np.random.randn(4096)
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(64,64))
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

    # Plot heatmap
    plt.sca(ax) # make the ax object the "current axes"
    plt.title(character)
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
    plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040745/9698684), you could do the following:

```
letter = "ABCDEFGH"

n_cols = 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=int(np.ceil(len(letter)/n_cols)), 
                         ncols=n_cols, 
                         figsize=(15,15))

for _, ax in zip(letter, axes.flatten()):
    x = np.random.randn(4096)
    y = np.random.randn(4096)
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(64,64))
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

    # Plot heatmap
    ax.set_title('Pythonspot.com heatmap example')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[image]