# How can a make a histogram for each item

Tags: python, pandas

I m trying to built a histogram for each item but when I trying to do that , i have only one histogram . This the code I have

```py
    for indicateur in indicator["Series Code"]:
        filtre_indic=data_sc['Indicator Code']==indicateur
        data_test = data_sc.loc[filtre_indic]['2000']
        data_test.hist()
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python plot multiple histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467077/python-plot-multiple-histograms)

Comment: no, when i try the solution of this post is not working

Comment: How does your data look like?