# How to create multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, data-science

I'm to Python and learning it by doing. I want to make two plots with matplotlib in Python. The second plot keeps the limits of first one. Wonder how I can change the limits of each next plot from previous. Any help, please. What is the recommended method?

```
X1 = [80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260]
Y1 = [70, 65, 90, 95, 110, 115, 120, 140, 155, 150]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(
    X1
  , Y1
  , color = "green"
  , marker = "o"
  , linestyle = "solid"
)
plt.show()


X2 = [80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200]
Y2 = [70, 65, 90, 95, 110, 115, 120]

plt.plot(
    X2
  , Y2
  , color = "green"
  , marker = "o"
  , linestyle = "solid"
)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

The quick and easy way; set the x and y limits in each plot to what you want.

```
plt.xlim(60,200)
plt.ylim(60,200)
```

(for example). Just paste those two lines just before both plt.show() and they'll be the same.

The harder, but better way and this is using subplots.

```
# create a figure object    
fig = plt.figure()
# create two axes within the figure and arrange them on the grid 1x2
ax1 = fig.add_Subplot(121)
# ax2 is the second set of axes so it is 1x2, 2nd plot (hence 122)
# they won't have the same limits this way because they are set up as separate objects, whereas in your example they are the same object that is being re-purposed each time!
ax2 = fig.add_Subplot(122)

ax1.plot(X1,Y1)
ax2.plot(X2,Y2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way for you using `subplot` where `plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)` means a figure with 1 row (first value) and 2 columns (second value) and 1st subfigure (third value in the bracket, meaning left column in this case). `plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)` means subplot in the 2nd column (right column in this case).

This way, each figure will adjust the x- and y-limits according to the data. There are another ways to do the same thing. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib) is a SO link for you.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
X1 = [80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260]
Y1 = [70, 65, 90, 95, 110, 115, 120, 140, 155, 150]
plt.plot(X1, Y1, color = "green", marker = "o", linestyle = "solid")
# plt.plot(X1, Y1, '-go') Another alternative to plot in the same style


plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
X2 = [80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200]
Y2 = [70, 65, 90, 95, 110, 115, 120]
plt.plot(X2, Y2, color = "green", marker = "o", linestyle = "solid")
# plt.plot(X2, Y2, '-go') Another alternative to plot in the same style
```

**Output**

[image]