# after groupby, set subplots into plots next to each-other rather than in one plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, subplot

After doing groupby in a pandas data-frame I wanna set subplots into different plots stacked next to eachother however, the module puts all of them in one plot

```
df.groupby('week')['label'].plot(kind='density', legend=True)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to look into using subplots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib

Comment: Please post data for a [mcve]. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looping through the `groupby` object and plot to corresponding axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

week_grps = df.groupby('week')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(week_grps), figsize=(15,5))

for ax,(i, sub) in zip(axs, week_grps):
    sub['label'].plot(kind='density', legend=True, title=i, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Hi bro. How can I for instance, put limit for x axis here? plt.xlim doesn't work?

Comment: Use the `xlim` argument in [`Series.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did it by ax.set_xlim

Comment: That would be the matplotlib-style and not pandas-style!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do

```py
df.groupby('week')['label'].plot(kind='density', legend=True, subplots=True)
```

Comment: OP will need to reshape data to wide since [subplots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) *make separate subplots for each column*.

Comment: no. adding subplots=True would just remove the colors but the curves will still remain in one plot. Thanks anyway!

Comment: True sorry about this

Comment: As mentioned @VahidGhafouri, your data needs to be pivoted to wide format for multiple columns. Try `df.pivot(columns='week', values='label').plot(kind='density', legend=True, subplots=True)`