# How to display all images from a single a multidimensional-array at once?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, display, mnist

I have a multidimensional array `(11, 28, 28)` which consists of 11 images, each with 28*28 pixels.

```
x_train_new_reshaped[0].shape

Out[8]: (11, 28, 28)
```

How can I display them all at once?

This results in:

```
In:
image = x_train_new_reshaped[0]
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()


Out:
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

This as well:

```
In:
image = np.squeeze(x_train_new_reshaped[0])
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

Out:
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want an image-plot as your code suggests, then the array should be 2D. Since you have multiple images stored in a 3D array, the easiest way would be to do a subplot for each image stored in your array and loop over them. With matplotlib you can find many examples how a subplot looks like, for example also here on stackoverflow: [How do I get multiple subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib)