# Python: Multiple Scatter Plots on a Grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, scatter-plot

I have been looking around, but I could not find a way to make a grid of scatter plots instead of ploting them all on one figure. Any idea on how to manipulate this for-loop to do so?

```
for i in range(1,8):
  plt.scatter(df_combi.iloc[:,1],df_combi.iloc[:,i+2])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `plt.subplots` for this

Comment: I see that it does 'something', but not getting it straight yet.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib) helps