# plt. in subplot works only for one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm new to python so I hope my question is good enough, 
I'm trying to create two subplots based on two different data frames.
My problem is that when I try to define titles and xlim it works only on one plot.

This is my script:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,6))

#Original data
df_codes.loc[:,float_cols_gb].T.plot(ax=axes[0])
plt.title('Original Data', size=(20))
plt.ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
plt.xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
plt.xlim(410,1004)

#filter  data
df_bl_codes.loc[:,float_cols_bl].T.plot(ax=axes[1])
plt.title( 'Filter', size=(20))
plt.ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
plt.xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
plt.xlim(410,1004)
```

I cannot attach image as i'm new user here, but the result is two plots, one gets the titles and the xlim (the one in column 1) and one stays without the ttiles and xlim (the one in column 0).

My end goal: to applly the xlimand also the titles to each plot in the subplots.

Comment: You should use a for loop over your axes to then use [`ax.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get multiple subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand what is happening, and help you improve the way you create your plots in the future.

The line

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,6))
```

creates two objects (everything in Python is an object): A [`matplotlib.pyplot.Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) object, and a list containing two [`matplotlib.pyplot.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) objects. When you then do something like `plt.title('Original Data', size=(20))`, `matplotlib` will add this title to what it deems to be the *current* `Axes` object—as you haven't told matplotlib which object this is, it will assume it is the first one in the array it just created. Unless you tell it otherwise (with [`plt.sca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.sca.html), but there is a better way), it will *always* assume this, and later calls to `plt.title()` will overwrite the previous value.

To fix this, use the built-in methods directly on the `Axes` objects instead. You can access these by indexing the `axes` list:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,6))

#Original data
df_codes.loc[:,float_cols_gb].T.plot(ax=axes[0])
axes[0].title('Original Data', size=(20))
axes[0].set_ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
axes[0].set_xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
axes[0].set_xlim(410,1004)

#filter  data
df_bl_codes.loc[:,float_cols_bl].T.plot(ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title( 'Filter', size=(20))
axes[1].set_ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
axes[1].set_xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
axes[1].set_xlim(410,1004)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of subplots, you should work with axes instances. 
Trying doing the following:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,6))

#Original data
df_codes.loc[:,float_cols_gb].T.plot(ax=axes[0])
ax[0].set_title('Original Data', size=(20))
ax[0].set_ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
ax[0].set_xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
ax[0].set_xlim(410,1004)

#filter  data
df_bl_codes.loc[:,float_cols_bl].T.plot(ax=axes[1])
ax[1].set_title( 'Filter', size=(20))
ax[1].set_ylabel('Reflectence', size=(14))
ax[1].set_xlabel('Wavelength', size=(14))
ax[1].set_xlim(410,1004)
```