# How to display multiple figure with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I try to display 3 figures only one window.

So I have a function make_graph(x) that make a figure of 2 subplots:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_graph(x):  
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    ax.scatter(x, [x ** 2], s = 50, color = 'blue')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
    ax.scatter(x, [x ** 3], s = 50, color = 'red')


make_graph(np.arange(10)) #figure_1
make_graph(np.arange(20)) #figure_2
make_graph(np.arange(30)) #figure_3
```

I want to display this 3 figures in a only one window, but actually, I have 3 windows opening.
I don't know how to code this.

Could you help?

Comment: Please check this post: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib). Your qestion is already answered.

Comment: No, it doesn't. this post is "how to display multiple subplots". I know how to get subplots (see the def make_graph()) . I only want to display 3 figures in the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a list of three parameters as arguments to the function and use the
So it draws the length of the list for a number of times (three).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_graph(x):  
    fig = plt.figure()
    pos = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        x = np.arange(val)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,pos[0][i])
        ax.scatter(x, [x ** 2], s = 50, color = 'blue')
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,pos[1][i])
        ax.scatter(x, [x ** 3], s = 50, color = 'red')

make_graph([10,20,30])
```