# Are there any ways to group matplotlib Figure instances together?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

I generated several matplotlib.figure.Figure instances from my customizaed function (just like the fig returns from plt.subplots()), but now I want to group them together as a large Figure without needing to rewrite the whole function, is it possible?

```
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots()
```

Is it possible to have some function to:

```
fig3 = some_function(fig1, fig2)
```

I have searched for similar questions and they usually points to plt.subplots(), I fully recognize I can do so with plt.subplots but I then need to rewrite everything, therefore I am asking here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get multiple subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney not really, I know plt.subplots can do it but my purpose is to combine the Figure instances return by plt.subplots().

Answer (score 0):

Rather than combine generated figures, you should combine generated plots. The `matplotlib.figure` library functions very similarly to the `matplotlib.pyplots` library. Since you are instantiating a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instance, you would generate some variation of the following basic code:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
```

The `matplotlib.figure.Figure` class has function called `add_subplot` that functions like `plt.subplots()`:

```
graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

With this foundation, you can add as many plots as you wish:

```
for i in data:
    graph.plot(data[x_values[i]], data[y_values[i]])
```

Note: `data` is just an arbitrary `pandas DataFrame` that can store all of your points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you guys help but the answers did not really correspond to my question. I knew that one shall use plt.subplots() but my question is about combining Figures after they have been created.

I didnt find a workaround, and just rewrite everything and adapt to plt.subplots().