# How do I change sizes of subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Google Colab and when I try to draw a graph it comes like this[image]

But I have to plot many graphs, so i used a for loop
[image]

I expected the graphs to be the same size as in the first image but I got all graphs in compressed form.
What should I do to obtain the graphs as the same size as in first image using a for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get multiple subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-do-i-get-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Besides changing the `figsize` which will only get you so far if you have a limited area for your plot, play around with `nrows` and `ncols` parameters of `plt.subplots`, as in the flagged question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with `figsize` parameter:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(no_of_feature, 1, figsize=(5, 10))  # example
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplot(no_of_features,1)
```

You create a single instance of figure, which has a predefined size. thus it will squeeze all the subplots to fit this figure size.

To increase the figure size you should run with the size the you wish before calling `plt.subplot`:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
```

Or you can create a new plot in each iteration in a different figure, which each image will have the original one size.

As @RichieV suggested, it also advisable to use different `nrows`/`ncols` to spread the subplots in the image.