# Using a nested for loop in subplots

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib, nested-loops

I am trying to use subplot from matplotlib to plot 6 figures with 2 figures per row. The plots are stored as strings in a list. For simplicity, I have a code that would print text instead of the actual plots below.

```
ab = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`
fig,axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row)

for i in range (3)
    for j in range(2)
         axes[i,j].text(0.5,0.5, str(f"{ab[i]}"), fontsize(18), ha='center')
fig
```

How can I write a for loop to achieve a final figure like this:
[image]

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: sorry about that, I just edited the post. The code provided does not result in the final image.

Comment: The easiest way is to flatten the array of subplots, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66949877/7758804) in the duplicate.

Comment: Use `zip`: `for a, ax in zip(ab, axes.flat):`, `ax.text(0.5, 0.5, a, fontsize=18, ha='center')`...

Comment: The above code works, except you want to do `{ab[i*2+j]}`