# Loop over axes to create scatterplots using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create 9 scatterplots using a target variable and 9 continuous variables.

I couldn't figure out a way to loop over each axis to plot scatterplots of each continuous variable against the target.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=3, figsize=(16, 8))
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont0'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[0, 0])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont1'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[0, 1])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont2'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[0, 2])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont3'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[1, 0])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont4'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[1, 1])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont5'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[1, 2])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont6'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[2, 0])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont7'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[2, 1])
sns.scatterplot(x=df['cont8'], y=df['target'], ax=ax[2, 2])
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Middle part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66052914/7758804): `for i, a_x in enumerate(ax.flatten()): sns.scatterplot(x=df[f'cont{i}'], y=df['target'], ax=a_x)`.

Comment: Thanks, this works for 9 variables. If I have 14 numerical variables and use a 5x3 grid, I get  ```KeyError: 'cont14'```. Is there a way to tell the for loop that I have 14 scatter plots?

Comment: You may have to adjust the pattern (`f'cont{i}'`) if the column names change. Otherwise use something more like option 2 of this answer where you create a list of the desired column names, zip them to the axes, and iterate.

Comment: It sounds like there are more `axes` the subplots. A simple solution would be to add `if i < 14:` into the loop before plotting.