# How can I create multiple countplot charts with loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

When I plot on a single chart with this code get a normal-looking chart.

```
df_bga= df.loc[(df['Dispensary'] == 'Lazy River Products')]
bga1= sns.countplot(y="Brand Name",data=df_bga)
bga1.set( title= " Flower Sku Count")
bga1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)
```

[image: Normal chart]

Loop chart code:

```
dispo = df_8th['Dispensary'].unique()
for i in dispo:
    df_loop= df.loc[(df['Dispensary'] == i)]
    c1= sns.countplot(y="Brand Name", data=df_loop)
    c1.set( title= i+" Flower Sku Count")
    c1.figure.savefig("count_charts/"+str(i) +" Brand Skus.png", format="PNG")
```

But when I try to loop through a bunch of data I get charts like this:
[image: Looped chart]

How do I loop through data and create multiple charts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots)

Comment: Section 2 of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804), just use `sns.countplot` for `df[col].plot`. You can also just do a `df.loc[df['Dispensary'].eq( i), "Brand Name"].value_counts().plot.bar()`, then there's no need for seaborn.

Comment: Otherwise, use `p = sns.catplot(kind='count', data=df_8th, col='Dispensary', col_wrap=3, y='Brand Name')`.

Comment: `sns.countplot(data=df_8th, y='Brand Name', hue='Dispensary')`

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay.