# Not able to use plt.subplots() for my data

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I am using the Lombscargle function to output the power spectrum for a signal I pass as input, I am able to get the plots one after another but the task at hand is to plot these graphs using subplots in a way that there are 5 rows, 4 cols.

An example for signal would be:

```
signal = [ '254.24', '254.32', '254.4', '254.84', '254.24', '254.28', '254.84', '253.56', '253.76', '253.32', '253.88', '253.72', '253.92', '251.56', '253.04', '244.72', '243.84', '246.08', '245.84', '249.0', '250.08', '248.2', '253.12', '253.2', '253.48', '253.88', '253.12', '253.4', '253.4']

from scipy.signal import lombscargle 

def LSP_scipy(signal):
    start_ang_freq = 2 * np.pi * (60/60)
    end_ang_freq = 2 * np.pi * (240/60)
    SAMPLES = 5000
    SAMPLE_SPACING = 1/15 

    t = np.linspace(0,len(signal)*SAMPLE_SPACING,len(signal))
    period_freq = np.linspace(start_ang_freq,end_ang_freq,SAMPLES)
    
    modified_signal_axis = []
    modified_time_axis = []
    for count,value in enumerate(signal):
        if value != 'None':
            modified_signal_axis.append(float(value))
            modified_time_axis.append(t[count])
        prog = lombscargle(modified_time_axis, modified_signal_axis, period_freq, normalize=False, precenter = True)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(period_freq,prog)
```

How do I plot these graphs in a matrix format?
[image: This is what I am getting after executing this code.]

Trying loop approach, [image: Result is this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- See inline comments to add and flatten the subplots.
- This is an implementation of flattening the `axes array` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) of the duplicate.

```py
from scipy.signal import lombscargle
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def LSP_scipy(signal):
    start_ang_freq = 2 * np.pi * (60/60)
    end_ang_freq = 2 * np.pi * (240/60)
    SAMPLES = 5000
    SAMPLE_SPACING = 1/15 

    t = np.linspace(0, len(signal)*SAMPLE_SPACING, len(signal))
    period_freq = np.linspace(start_ang_freq, end_ang_freq, SAMPLES)
    
    modified_signal_axis = []
    modified_time_axis = []
    
    # create the figure and subplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 6, figsize=(20, 9), sharex=False, sharey=False)
    
    # flatten the array
    axes = axes.ravel()
    
    for count, value in enumerate(signal):
        if value != 'None':
            modified_signal_axis.append(float(value))
            modified_time_axis.append(t[count])
        prog = lombscargle(modified_time_axis, modified_signal_axis, period_freq, normalize=False, precenter=True)
        
        # plot
        axes[count].plot(period_freq, prog)
        
        # format the axes
        axes[count].set(title=value)
        # some plot have an exponential offset on the yaxis, this turns it off
        axes[count].ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
        # some yaxis values are long floats, this formats them to 3 decimal places
        axes[count].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.3f'))
        
    # format the figure
    fig.tight_layout()


signal = [ '254.24', '254.32', '254.4', '254.84', '254.24', '254.28', '254.84', '253.56', '253.76', '253.32', '253.88', '253.72', '253.92', '251.56', '253.04', '244.72', '243.84', '246.08', '245.84', '249.0', '250.08', '248.2', '253.12', '253.2', '253.48', '253.88', '253.12', '253.4', '253.4']
LSP_scipy(signal[:20])  # as per comment, only first 20
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Trenton! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AMANDEEPKAUR You're welcome, I'm glad this works for you. Since it's essentially the same implementation as the duplicate answer I closed the question to, I posted this answer as a community wiki. I don't accumulate rep for this answer, so feel free to upvote the linked answer, if you're inclined. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop and iterate over subplots. A very simple example is shown below.The subplots method creates the figure along with the subplots and store in the `ax` array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = range(10)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

for row in ax:
   for col in row:
      col.plot(x, y)


plt.show()

# or you can also do

for in range(2):         # row=0, col=0
  for j in range(2):     # row=0, col=1
     ax[i, j].plot(x,y)  # row=1, col=0
                         # row=1, col=1
```

Comment: Hey I did try this approach, but I am not getting the desired results. Refer the last image, after trying your soln, I have 20 entries, and want all of them in 1 matrix.

Comment: what is signal here?

Comment: For each plot there should be one pair of x-values and y-values(x, y), I don't understand how you got multiple plots in the first place with the line `ax.plot(period_freq,prog)` in your code(cause it generates a single plot). Post a reproducible example.

Comment: Like the example of signal I gave, I have 20 such more rows, which are fed sequentially to the code stated above, I want each rows result forms as 1 grid element In the 5x4 matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I used this approach and was able to solve the problem.

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Then one idea is to take the signals into an array of `shape=(20,1)`, where each row corresponds to signal amplitude or some other measurable quantity. Then you could do as below (check the output keeping only the lines till `plt.text` you will get the idea).

```
 for i in range(1, 21):
    plt.subplot(5, 4, i)
    plt.text(0.5, 0.5, str((5, 4, i)),
         fontsize=18, ha='center')
    # Call the function here...get the value of period_freq and prog
    period_freq,prog = LSP_scipy(signal[i])
    plt.plot(period_freq, prog)
```