# using index with subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

Tags: python, matplotlib

hi I would like to know if there is a way to get matplotlib.pyplot.subplots() to always be subscriptable. for example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax[0,0].plot([1,2,3],[2,4,8])
```

The code above works as expected, but if I change the number of rows and cols to 1 I get

```
ax[0,0].plot([1,2,3],[2,4,8])
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable
```

which is normally ok, but I don't want to change all instances of ax[0,0] to ax everytime I want to plot one graph.

Comment: The best option is to flatten the axes array with `ax = ax.ravel()`, then it can be indexed with `ax[0]`, `ax[1]`. Otherwise, set `squeeze=False`: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, squeeze=False)`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) of the duplicate.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes that is it, thank you