# How to overlay data points on a barplot with a categorical axis

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, facet-grid, stripplot

**Goal:** I am trying to show individual data points in a figure with multiple grouped bar charts using Seaborn.

**Problem:** I tried to do it with a catplot for the bar chart and another catplot for the individual data points. However, this generates 2 figures: One figure with the bar chart and the other with the individual data points.

**Question:** Is there a way to show the individual data points in the same figure together with the bar chart using Seaborn?

This is my code generating 2 separate figures:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.catplot(
    x="sex", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="smoker", 
    row="time", 
    data=tips, 
    kind="bar", 
    ci = "sd", 
    edgecolor="black",
    errcolor="black",
    errwidth=1.5,
    capsize = 0.1,
    height=4, 
    aspect=.7,
)

g = sns.catplot(
    x="sex", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="smoker", 
    row="time", 
    data=tips, 
    kind="strip", 
    height=4, 
    aspect=.7,
)
```

Output:

[image: My output]

**Question:** Is there a way to show the individual data points in the same figure together with the bar chart using Seaborn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Figure-level plots ([`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)) may not be combined, however, it's possible to map an axes-level plot ([`seaborn.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)) onto a figure-level plot.

  - See [Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
  - This can be a temperamental process, and may only work when the same columns from the dataframe are being used in the mapped plot.
- `palette=sns.color_palette()[:2]` ensures the correct colors are used for the overlying markers, and `[:2]` selects the first two colors, which correspond to the colors use by `hue='smoker'`.

  - If a custom `palette` is specified for `catplot`, use it in `.map`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.catplot(
    x="sex", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="smoker", 
    row="time", 
    data=tips, 
    kind="bar", 
    errorbar = "sd", 
    edgecolor="black",
    errcolor="black",
    errwidth=1.5,
    capsize = 0.1,
    height=4, 
    aspect=.7,
    alpha=0.5)

# map data to stripplot
g.map(sns.stripplot, 'sex', 'total_bill', 'smoker', hue_order=['Yes', 'No'], order=['Male', 'Female'],
      palette=sns.color_palette()[:2], dodge=True, alpha=0.6, ec='k', linewidth=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- `seaborn.catplot` is a figure-level plot, and they can't be combined.
- As shown below, axes-level plots like `seaborn.barplot` and `seaborn.stripplot` can be plotted to the same `axes`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.barplot(
    x="sex", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="smoker", 
    data=tips, 
    ci="sd", 
    edgecolor="black",
    errcolor="black",
    errwidth=1.5,
    capsize = 0.1,
    alpha=0.5
)

sns.stripplot(
    x="sex", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="smoker", 
    data=tips, dodge=True, alpha=0.6, ax=ax
)

# remove extra legend handles
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[2:], labels[2:], title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how do you overlay data points on bar plots in a figure with multiple rows or columns, as stated in my code section _(row="time")_. Is there a way to do this? @Trenton McKinney

Comment: @AlexSchubert See [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) for creating subplots with multiple rows and columns and then you would assign the barplot and stripplot to the same axes.