# seaborn boxplot and stripplot points aren't aligned over the x-axis by hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have the following code to draw a boxplot and overlay all data points on the bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random as rnd

f = plt.figure(figsize=[18,12])
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
sns.boxplot(x='month', y='ffdi', hue='scenario', data=df_diff_concat, ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(x="month", y="ffdi",hue='scenario', data=df_diff_concat, ax=ax)
```

[image]

The data points are not vertically aligned with the middleline of the bar they belong to.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 7):

- Use `dodge=True` in [`seaborn.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html), otherwise the values are plotted as a single group centered over the x-tick
- See [How to overlay data points on a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69398767/7758804) figure-level plot, where the `kind='bar'` can be replaced with `kind='box'`
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load the dataframe
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu")

# add stripplot with dodge=True
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu", dodge=True, ax=ax, ec='k', linewidth=1)

# remove extra legend handles
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2], title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

- To get the points all in a single line, also set `jitter=False`, but all data points won't show when there's overlap.

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu")

# add stripplot with dodge=True
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu",
              dodge=True, ax=ax, ec='k', linewidth=1, jitter=False)

# remove extra legend handles
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2], title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

- Use [`seaborn.swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html), which is similar to `stripplot()`, but the points are adjusted (only along the categorical axis) so that they don’t overlap.

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu")

# add stripplot with dodge=True
sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="GnBu",
              dodge=True, ax=ax, ec='k', linewidth=1, size=3)

# remove extra legend handles
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:2], labels[:2], title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]