# Legend from seaborn box-plot disrupts the alignment with overlayed swarm-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, swarmplot

edit: solved here

[seaborn boxplot and stripplot points aren't aligned over the x-axis by hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458775/seaborn-boxplot-and-stripplot-points-arent-aligned-over-the-x-axis-by-hue)

In the above case, the swarmplot was shifted in the overlay and the resolution was achieved from setting dodge = true in swarmplot.

Here, the boxplot was shifted, the resolution was achieved from setting dodge = False in barplot.

---

I have a seaborn boxplot overlayed with a seaborn swarmplot.  Whenever I add labels to my boxplot, the legend repositions the boxplot without adjusting the swarmplot (fig 1).
[image: Fig1]

```
sns.swarmplot(x = 'data_type', y = 'count', data = df, 
                   alpha = .5, palette='colorblind', hue='data_type', legend = 0, zorder=0.5)


ax = sns.boxplot(x = 'data_type', y = 'count', data = df,
                 palette='colorblind', showfliers = 0, hue = 'data_type')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.02, 1), loc = 'upper left')
```

If I remove the labels, through omitting
`hue = 'data_type'`
then I have the alignment I want (fig 2).
[image: Fig2]

How can I display the boxplot legend while preserving alignment?

Comment: `ax = sns.swarmplot(…)` then `sns.boxplot(…, ax=ax)` and `ax.legend(…)`

Comment: Additionally, it is redundant and unnecessary to use `hue` because the labels are already on the x-axis.

Comment: @jylls [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880582/legend-from-seaborn-box-plot-disrupts-the-alignment-with-overlayed-swarm-plot?noredirect=1#comment133844744_75880582) shows the correct way to assign and reuse the matplotlib.axes returned by seaborn. The duplicates already explain dodge and hue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to set `dodge=False` when calling the `boxplot` function. See doc [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) for more info and see code below:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.swarmplot(data=tips,x="day",y="total_bill",hue='day',legend=0,ax=ax)
sns.boxplot(data=tips,x="day", y="total_bill",hue='day',showfliers = 0,ax=ax,dodge=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.02, 1), loc = 'upper left')
```

[image]