# histogram plot issue for numeric features in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram here but i keep getting an error

```
numeric_features = ['tenure', 'MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges']

cols = 3
rows = int( np.ceil( len(numeric_features)/ cols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(16,16))

for i in range(len(numeric_features)):
    this_row = int(np.floor(i/cols))
    this_col = int(i%cols)
    feat = numeric_features[i]
    this_ax = axes[this_row][this_col]
    this_ax.hist(df_train[feat], bins=25)
    this_ax.set_title(feat)
 
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It throws the below error:

[image]

where am i going wrong here?? i am just trying to plot the numeric values of a dataset.

Comment: For multiple row numbers in subplots, isn't the format `axes[this_row, this_col]`?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804): `axes = axes.ravel()` and then see **4.** about zipping an axes to the data, or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804) which is specific to dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you determine the row values, you get `1`, and as such, the axes is not an array of lists as you expect them to be, it is instead just a list of axes.

Print out your axes and see for yourself. That can be the best way to debug issues like these. Look at the actual variables where errors are occurring to verify your assumptions about structure or type are actually correct. Your method works only for when `rows > 1`.

I'll leave you to work out an approach to account for the case when `rows = 1` but feel free to respond and I (or anyone else) can offer more advice.