# How to resolve line in subplot is not visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm trying to show speed vs velocity vs acceleration. The specific numbers don't really matter, just the concept. The last graph isn't showing a line with a  slope of zero (ex: y=10). I want the program to show it with the x values of the graph being the same as the others (1 to 10). The specific numbers don't matter except for the x-values because I won't be showing the y-values. I just want a 0 slope line to be visible T-T

```py
t = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
spd_graph = np.exp(t/2)
velo_graph = 3*t
accel_graph = .5
# plot speed
ax1 = plt.subplot(311,ylabel='Speed')
plt.plot(t, spd_graph,'c')
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=6)
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.ylim(0,30)
plt.xlim(0,10)
# plot velocity
ax2 = plt.subplot(312,ylabel='Velocity')
plt.plot(t,velo_graph,'g')
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=6)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.ylim(0,30)
plt.xlim(0,10)
# plot acceleration
ax3 = plt.subplot(313,label='Acceleration',xlabel='Time',ylabel='Acceleration')
plt.plot(accel_graph,'b')
plt.setp(ax3.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=6)
plt.setp(ax3.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.ylim(0,30)
plt.xlim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

On subplot `ax3`, `plt.plot(accel_graph, 'b')` is trying to plot a single float value, which won't work.
You need to either:

1. make sure `accel_graph` is an array (or list) the same shape as `t`, e.g., `accel_graph = 0.5*np.ones(t.shape)`, then `plt.plot(t, accel_graph, 'b')`, or something similar (e.g., `plt.plot([min(t), max(t)], [0.5, 0.5], 'b')`
2. plot a horizontal line; instead of the `plt.plot(accel_graph, 'b')` line, do something like `ax3.axhline(0.5, color='b')` (note that this will result in a horizontal line that extends beyond the minimum and maximum `t` values you have)

- In addition, you're not correctly using the object oriented API. It should be `ax1.plot(...)`, `ax2.plot(...)`, `ax3.plot(...)`, in addition to other changes.

  - Also see [Multiple Subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html)
  - [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726643/7758804)

```py
t = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
spd_graph = np.exp(t/2)
velo_graph = 3*t
accel_graph = .5

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=False)

# plot speed
ax1.plot(t, spd_graph,'c')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=6)
ax1.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax1.set(ylabel='Speed', ylim=(0, 30), xlim=(0, 10))

# plot velocity
ax2.plot(t, velo_graph,'g')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=6)
ax2.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax2.set(ylabel='Velocity', ylim=(0, 30), xlim=(0, 10))

# plot acceleration
ax3.hlines(accel_graph, t[0], t[-1])
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=6)
ax3.axes.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax3.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Acceleration', ylim=(0, 1), xlim=(0, 10))

plt.show()
```

[image]