# Seaborn Concatenated Bar Charts Different Colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have this dataframe called cases_deaths:

```
   week daily_case_totals   daily_death_totals
0   1   2.0                 0.0
1   2   12.0                0.0
2   3   12.0                0.0
3   4   2.0                 0.0
4   5   573.0               6.0
5   6   3134.0              12.0
6   7   3398.0              32.0
7   8   992.0               25.0
.
.
.
```

And this code to generate to Seaborn charts:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(11, 10))
for name, ax in zip(['daily_case_totals', 'daily_death_totals'], axes):
    sns.barplot(data=cases_deaths, x='week', y=name, ax=ax, color = 'red')
```

And the chart looks like this:
[image: chart]

But I want the top one to be blue and bottom to be red. Not sure how to do that, I've tried passing in a list of colors to the color parameter in the for loop but that yielded an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots) and this [answer (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more iterable to `zip` for the colors:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(11, 10))
for name, color, ax in zip(('daily_case_totals', 'daily_death_totals'),
                           ('blue', 'red'),
                           axes):
    sns.barplot(data=cases_deaths, x='week', y=name, ax=ax, color=color)
```

[image: multicolor plot]