# Using arrays as values with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’m currently trying to plot the data I recieve from an API (Hypixel), by pushing the values into an array and using that array as input for a matplotlib graph. I wanted to make sure it worked, so I made a test program (see below), and sure enough I couldn’t get it to work. I’m completely lost, so I just wanted to ask if any of you knew how to use an array as input for a matplotlib.
Thanks :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

ab = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

ord = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([ab], [ord])
```

Comment: which kind of plot do you want for your data?

Comment: @Lalaryk what's the error? if you want to plot the lines try with `ax.plot(ab, ord)`

Comment: I don’t feel like I have been very clear with my intentions. Basically I want to use arrays so that whenever I want I can just append them, and update the graph so I can get a dynamic graph of sorts

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

ab = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

ord = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

plt.plot(ab,'g*', ord, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this post:
[How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots)

Where they define number of subplots and then specify which values to be plotted where as you are using subplots.

If you want to plot ab on Y-axis and ord on X-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ab = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ord = [1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8]

plt.plot(ab, ord)
plt.show()
```