# How to create subplots of all column combinations from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot

I have a made a function which plots input variables against predicted variables.

```
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=65.5,high=140.5,size=(50,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
dummy_predicted = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=15.5,high=17.5,size=(50,4)), columns=list('WXYZ'))

##Plot test input distriubtions
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
n_rows = 1 
n_cols = 4
counter = 1
for i in dummy_data.keys():
    plt.subplot(n_rows, n_cols, counter)
    plt.scatter(dummy_data[i], dummy_predicted['Z'])

    plt.title(f'{i} vs Z')
    plt.xlabel(i)
    counter += 1

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I create a 4 x 4 subplot of all combinations of 'ABCD' and 'WXYZ'? I can have any number of `dummy_data` and `dummy_predicted` columns so some dynamism would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do a double for loop

```
n_rows = len(dummy_data.columns)
n_cols = len(dummy_predicted.columns)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(15,6))

for row, data_col in enumerate(dummy_data):
    for col, pred_col in enumerate(dummy_predicted):
        ax = axes[row][col]

        ax.scatter(dummy_data[data_col], dummy_predicted[pred_col])
        
        ax.set_title(f'{data_col} vs {pred_col}')

        ax.set_xlabel(data_col)

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the standard library, to create all combinations of column names, `combos`.
- Use the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of each set of columns to determine `nrows` and `ncols` for [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)
- Flatten the array of `axes` to easily iterate through a 1D array instead of a 2D array.
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) `combos` and `axes` to iterate through, and plot each group with a single loop.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) in [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726643/7758804).

```py
from itertools import product
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# sample data
np.random.seed(2022)
dd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=65.5, high=140.5, size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
dp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=15.5, high=17.5, size=(50, 4)), columns=list('WXYZ'))

# create combinations of columns
combos = product(dd.columns, dp.columns)

# create subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(dd.columns), ncols=len(dp.columns), figsize=(15, 6))

# flatten axes into a 1d array
axes = axes.flat

# iterate and plot
for (x, y), ax in zip(combos, axes):
    ax.scatter(dd[x], dp[y])
    ax.set(title=f'{x} vs. {y}', xlabel=x, ylabel=y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]