# Create scatter subplots between two subsets of pandas columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1], 
                            [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6], 
                            [0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6]]),  
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'X', 'Y'])
```

and I want to perform all possible scatter plots between two subsets of columns: `set1 = ['a', 'b']`, and `set2 = ['X', 'Y']`. I'd like to place all these subplots in a "matrix" like:

```
size_set1 = len(set1)
size_set2 = len(set2)
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(size_set1,size_set2), figsize=(30,30));
```

This is as far as I got, but this code does not produce scatter plots, and it just seems to plot each column instead of columns against each other.

The desired output should be (for this example) 4 scatter plots, `(X,a), (X,b), (Y,a), (Y,b)`, arranged 2 above and 2 below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# added for layout; delete these two lines if you want "blank" plots
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1], 
                            [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6], 
                            [0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6]]),  
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'X', 'Y'])

set1 = ['a', 'b']
set2 = ['X','Y']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(set1), ncols=len(set2), figsize=[12,12])

xmin = 0
xmax = 0.8

ymin = 0
ymax = 0.8

for i in range(len(set1)):
    for j in range(len(set2)):
        ax[i,j].scatter(df[set2[j]], df[set1[i]])
        ax[i,j].set_xlabel(set2[j])
        ax[i,j].set_ylabel(set1[i])
        
        ax[i,j].title.set_text(f'plot ({set2[j]},{set1[i]})')
        
        ax[i,j].set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
        ax[i,j].set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

fig.suptitle("Scatter plots", fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: scatter plot]

If you want to extend this with a column `c`, we can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1], 
                            [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6], 
                            [0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6]]),  
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'X', 'Y'])

# also adjust the set, of course:
set1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Result:

[image: scatter plot2]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1], 
                            [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6], 
                            [0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6]]),  
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'X', 'Y'])

set1 = ['a', 'b']
set2 = ['X', 'Y']

size_set1 = len(set1)
size_set2 = len(set2)

pairs = list(itertools.product(set1,set2))

for i in range(len(pairs)):
    plt.subplot(size_set2, size_set1, i+1)
    plt.scatter(df[pairs[i][0]], df[pairs[i][1]])

plt.show()
```

See also this this question and the answers: [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots)

Comment: Yes, but there are too many elements to do it manually like this.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I edited the answer. Is this more useful?
Unfortunately, I also don't have a solution to do it with pandas.DataFrame.plot .