# plotting two QQ plots side by side

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

i'm trying to plot two QQ plots side by side. I looked at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726643/how-to-plot-in-multiple-subplots) but not sure how to assign them still. A Q–Q plot quantile-quantile plot) is a probability plot to comparing two probability distributions by plotting their quantiles against each other.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

x, y = df['total_bill'], df['tip']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stats.probplot(x, dist='norm', plot=ax)
stats.probplot(y, dist='norm', plot=ax)
plt.title ('QQ plot x and y')
plt.savefig ( 'qq.png', dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two subplots intially and then assign the stats.probplot() to each of the axes. Updated code below. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

x, y = df['total_bill'], df['tip']
## Indicate number of rows and columns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))

## Create first subplot and assign it to the first plot ax[0]
stats.probplot(x, dist='norm', plot=ax[0])
## Optionally, remove the default title text
ax[0].set_title('')

## Repeat for second plot at ax[1]
stats.probplot(y, dist='norm', plot=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('')

## Add single title with name you want
fig.suptitle('QQ plot x and y', fontsize=15)
```

[image]