# looping through dictionary keys to plot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
habitat_dictionary={'trees':6,
                    'ponds':10,
                    'scrub':23}
```

I also have a dataframe with many columns, among which are no._trees, no._ponds, no._scrub -for example:

```
d = {'no._trees': [1, 2], 'no._rabbit_holes':[7,8],'no._ponds':[3,5], 'no._scrub':[3,2],'robin': [0.5, 0.6], 'dove':[0.6,0.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

For each key in the habitat dictionary, I want to create a graph with the key as the x-axis variable, a y-axis variable between 0 and 1, and there would be two lines: one for 'robin' and one for 'dove'.

I have been trying this:

```
for habitat  in habitat_dictionary.keys():
    out=df.set_index('no._'+str(habitat))[['robin', 'dove']

    out.plot(ylim=(0, 1), xticks=out.index, legend=True)
```

but I am getting the error: 'TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method'

I would like to have all the graphs as subplots with a shared title

Comment: I've voting to close this because the reported error is not reproducible. The code creates 3 plots without issue. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkW3u.png). Otherwise review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804) in [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726643/7758804)

Comment: Oh, I'll will investigate more my error then....how would I get them as subplots with a shared title?

Comment: I updated my previous comment.

Comment: You may want to look into using [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html). That link includes many examples.