# Adding Percentage Change Values to Bar Charts in a For Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

I have created a series of separate bar charts using a for loop (not the subplot mechanism), but now would like to add the percentage change by year as the bar label. I have created two separate df's in Python to hold the level values and the percentage change values. I was able to output the correct bar chart with the correct percentage change as the bar label, but it also began outputting WAY too many bar charts. Many more than I have in my df. This is most likely due to the nested for loops, but I haven't been able to find a way around this that works.

My dataframes are setup in the same way (with the index being the years 2013-2027 and each column being a category with yearly data). I also identify a special timeframe to use for my bar chart creation. The ak df is the one with levels and akp is the one with percentage changes. I would like to create separate bar charts using the level data in ak, then add the percentage changes found in akp to the bar labels. The below code gives me what I'm looking for ~generally~, but is also creating way to many graphs. How can I get it to generate 1 graph per column in the ak df, while using the akp df for ONLY bar labels?

```
ak = ak.set_index("combo")
ak = ak.T
akp = ak.pct_change()
colors = ['blue', 'blue','blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red' ]
timeframe = ak["2019":"2026"]
timeframe1 = akp["2019":"2026"]

for i in timeframe.columns:
    for i in timeframe1.columns:
        plt.figure()
        barplot = plt.bar(timeframe.index, timeframe[i], color = colors)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.ylabel('A')
        plt.bar_label(barplot, labels = round(timeframe1[i],2), label_type= "edge")
```

Comment: [Subplots with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804)

Comment: `labels=timeframe1[i].round(2).astype(str).add('%')`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand without some sample data, but:

1. I can see you are using i for both loops; 2. if you are creating figures in the nested loop, the number of figures the code will create is N * N, where N is the number of columns.

Does this solve your problem?

```
for i in timeframe.columns:
    plt.figure()
    barplot = plt.bar(timeframe.index, timeframe[i], color = colors)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.ylabel('A')
    plt.bar_label(barplot, labels = round(timeframe1[i],2), label_type= "edge")

    # if you want percentage signs try using an iterator:
    plt.bar_label(barplot, labels = [str(v) + '%' for v in round(timeframe1[i],2)], label_type= "edge")
```