Line plot of multiple data sets with different x axis coordinates
I have data organized like this:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.DataFrame({(1,'x'):[0,1,2],(1,'y'):[10,11,12],
                   (2,'x'):[1,2,3],(2,'y'):[11.5,11.8,13.2]})
df

   1      2      
   x   y  x     y
0  0  10  1  11.5
1  1  11  2  11.8
2  2  12  3  13.2

In words: I have data sets for several items, and each data set consists of a number of x/y pairs, but each data set has its own, different set of x values.
Now, I want to plot all data on the same plot, like this:

I can do it easily with a loop, like this:
fig1,ax = plt.subplots()
for item in range(1,3):
    df.xs(item,axis=1,level=0).plot(ax=ax,kind='line',x='x',y='y',
                                    style='o-',label=str(item))

But I wonder if there's a way to get the same plot without using a loop.

It seems that you are not familiar with how to create a basic subplots. refer to the following post to learn about basic subplots first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284590/20430449

Sorry, but this has nothing to do with subplots. See ouroboros1 answer below.

Transform your df before applying df.plot: index for x-axis values and separate columns for y-axis values. Here's one approach:

Add level 0 from the columns to the index with df.stack and drop the original index (df.droplevel).
Append column x to the index using df.set_index with append=True.
Get level 0 back to the columns with df.unstack and drop the other column level (i.e. 0 on axis=1).

out = (
    df.stack(0)
    .droplevel(0)
    .set_index('x', append=True)
    .unstack(0)
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
)

out

      1     2
x            
0  10.0   NaN
1  11.0  11.5
2  12.0  11.8
3   NaN  13.2

This we can easily plot:
out.plot(kind='line', style='o-')
plt.show()

Plot


Thank you @ouroboros1. Pretty obvious in hindsight. My df will have a lot of NaNs as none of the x values are the same.

Since your dataframe is not in a format directly suitable for plotting, my suggestion is to melt it into long-format before plotting:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
df = pd.DataFrame({(1,'x'):[0,1,2],(1,'y'):[10,11,12],(2,'x'):[1,2,3],(2,'y'):[11.5,11.8,13.2]})

reformatted_data = []

for (item, coord), values in df.items():
    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        if len(reformatted_data) <= index:
            reformatted_data.append({'Item': item})
        if 'X' not in reformatted_data[index] or item == reformatted_data[index]['Item']:
            reformatted_data[index][coord] = value
            reformatted_data[index]['Item'] = item  
df_corrected = pd.DataFrame(reformatted_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for item in df_corrected['Item'].unique():
    item_data = df_corrected[df_corrected['Item'] == item]
    ax.plot(item_data['x'], item_data['y'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label=f'Item {item}')

ax.legend()
plt.show()

which gives

